# ¿Cómo hago para que no se repitan los datos en mi colección?

Tags: c#, webforms

¿De qué forma podré registrar datos sin que se dupliquen en mi btnRegistrar?

Tengo problemas al visualizar los datos cada vez que registro datos me los duplica, la idea que no me duplique en mi tabla donde los tengo registrado.

```
protected void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
   Mascota m = new Mascota();
            
   m.Id = int.Parse(txtIdentificador.Text);
   m.Nombre = txtNombreMascota.Text;
   m.Tipo = ddlTipoMascota.Text;
   m.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
   m.FechaUltimaVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text);
   m.NombreDuenio = txtNombreDuenio.Text;
   m.EmailContacto = txtEmail.Text;
   mas.Add(m);
}
```

Comment: Cual es el criterio q hay q tener en cuenta para saber si ese dato ya existe? el nombre o alguna otra propiedad?

Comment: identificador, es quien al momento de registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo aquí te dejo una:

```
protected void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                      
   int id = int.Parse(txtIdentificador.Text);         
   var cantidadRepeticiones = mas.Count(m => m.id == id); 
   
   if(cantidadRepeticiones == 0)
   { 
      Mascota m = new Mascota();

      m.id = id;
      m.Nombre = txtNombreMascota.Text;
      m.Tipo = ddlTipoMascota.Text;
      m.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
      m.FechaUltimaVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text);
      m.NombreDuenio = txtNombreDuenio.Text;
      m.EmailContacto = txtEmail.Text;
      mas.Add(m);
   }
}
```

Aquí se hace uso de **Linq** para contar los elementos que ya existen en la lista de mascotas que son iguales al nuevo id de la mascota que se quiere insertar, si ese conteo de repeticiones da **0** quiere decir que no existe ninguna mascota con ese id, por tanto se procede a guardarla en la lista de mascotas, si el conteo da un número mayor a **0**, pues indica que ya existen mascotas con ese id, por tanto no se guarda la mascota.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: vale amigo(a) me sirvio de mucho, nunca iba a llegar a la solucion de usar el Linq, gracias!!

Comment: igual de que forma podre usar un modificar, es casi de esta misma manera?

Comment: @CristianGuerreroNenen te recomiendo q hagas una nueva publicacion para esta nueva pregunta que tienes y ahi expliques bien lo nuevo que quieras hacer

Comment: listo pa hay la relize